# Best approach to update an existing event in multiple Microsoft accounts using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: api, events, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am working on a calendar synchronization between my application and personal calendars of the users. The idea is that every time an event is created or updated, this event is sent to the personal calendar of the users (they can choose syncing to Google Calendar and/or Microsoft accounts calendar).

I have this complete flow working with Google Calendar and now I am working with Microsoft oAuth and Graph API to make it work either for MS Calendars.

Currently, for MS, I have the following scenario implemented and working:

- User authorizes the application to access its calendar through consent page
- Server exchanges the authorization code for an access token
- I can insert an event in user's calendar using its access token as Authorzation header through Microsoft Graph API (POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events)

Now I am trying to figure out how I can manage event updates (when start date changes, for instance, how I will send this update for each user's MS account), knowing the following constraints of Microsoft Events API:

- Property "ICalUId" is generated by MS API itself and returned in the response of Insert endpoint. I can't insert an event with my own ICalUId. This is possible with Google Calendar and very useful, because if I send an event with an existing iCalUId to [import endpoint](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/import), Google updates this existing event with the sent data, and if the iCalUId doesn't exist, Google creates the event (it performs an upsert-like action).
- For each event inserted at different users calendar, a new "ICalUId" is generated, even if I am sending the same event object to insert. So I get many iCalUId's for the same event, this adds complex in tracking this event in users calendars, different from Google Calendar as I mentioned before.

So that's the challenge I am facing right now. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have tried adding custom data to the event using custom extensions? This way you can track the event as the custom data can only be changed by you. See [Create Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/opentypeextension-post-opentypeextension?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) on how to try this.

Comment: @Danstan thanks for your suggestion! In fact it looks useful for my case, I was able to create with a custom information. But now I am trying to figure out how  to filter by this specific custom data. I am looking Microsoft Graph examples on filtering extensions, but some of them are quite confusing. Do you know how to filter by this custom data?

Comment: @Danstan I am using $expand to retrieve the extension data (like [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/opentypeextension-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-3)). But I am not figuring out how to filter by the a value in the extension.

Comment: I am happy to help. As for filter, try `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$filter=extensions/any(f:f/id eq 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.OpenTypeExtension.Com.Something.OwnerId')` where `id` in the any operator can be any supported sub field of the extension

Comment: If this solves your case let me know so that I can put together a better clear answer.